# How do I assign items that belong to one half of "has many :through" with the other half of the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm trying to model my database in Ruby and can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrolled_ins
    has_many :users, :through => :enrolled_ins
    has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrolled_ins
    has_many :courses, :through => :enrolled_ins
end

class EnrolledIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :courses
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :courses
end
```

I want to add that when a user picks a course, they can select the different events that they want with that course, and those are assigned to them instead of them getting all the events.

Comment: I'd study relational database modeling and design.

Comment: I know the theory behind it but I am new to ruby and have no idea how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a UserEvents join. When you add a course, you would see a list of available events. Assuming you have a form with checkboxes, you would create the UserEvent records. I don't think you would need all 3 ID values (user, event, course). Course is just a way to group the various events.

```
class UserEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I'd also add a dependent destroy on user and on event do destroy the join records if either side is removed.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at it all wrong trying to add something to the EnrolledIn model.